# Dual space as analogous of inner products, what does it mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, duality-theorems

Currently reading through [Optimization by Vector Space methods](https://www.google.co.kr/books/edition/Optimization_by_Vector_Space_Methods/lZU0CAH4RccC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Optimization%20by%20Vector%20Space%20Methods%20pdf&printsec=frontcover), specifically chapter 5 *Dual Spaces*.

I've read several times about this topic, but there's a specific insight here that I've never thought of, which I quote.

> *Dual space plays a role analogous to the inner product in Hilbert Space; by suitable interpretation we can develop results extending the projection theorem solution of minimum norm problems to arbitrary normed linear spaces.*

The analogy in this book is given in the context of optimisation. But I wonder if something some other analogies can be extrapolated.

As examples I am thinking the following.

**Series expansion**. Say you have an Hilbert Space $X$ with a orthonormal basis $\left\{\phi_j\right\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}$ then any vector $x \in X$ can be written uniquely as

$$
x = \sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}} \left\langle x, \phi_j \right\rangle \phi_j
$$

Can these expansions be generalized using Dual Spaces whenever the space is not a Hilbert one?

I would be thrilled to learn about more about these analogies.